# Slave unreliably sends bit 7

Tags: i2c, raspberrypi

I'm trying to send a byte from an Arduino Nano I2C slave to a Raspberry Pi 3B Master by directly connecting the two I2C pins of each device with no external pull-ups or level converters. It mostly works but the high bit is sometimes misread as a 0 when it should be a 1.

It seems to be caused by that bit being put on the data line at the same time as the clock rising edge so it's not clearly a 0 or a 1. Here's a scope trace showing what I think the problem is for slave address 4 (binary 0000100) and data 231 (binary 11100111). Why is it doing that and how can I fix it?

[image: Scope trace]

Another guess is that the Raspberry Pi might be holding the data line low and blocking the slave's value.

Using Wire library on the Arduino and SMBus on the Pi.

EDIT: I added a level converter and the problem is still there, so it's not caused by the 3.3V/5V difference.

Comment: With no pull-up and no level converter you shouldn't expect it to work.  Actually it may damage the Pi unless you have the Nano running at 3v3.

Comment: @Delta_G Pi has internal 3.3V pull-ups and Nano has higher-valued pull-ups to 5V which don't seem to cause any problem since signals are all 3.3V as shown in scope.

Comment: Depending on the speed, the built-in pull-ups might be too large. What happens if you add external pull-ups?

Comment: The waveforms aren't rounded off and the voltages are easily correct. How could too-high pullups affect the timing of one or two pulses but none of the others?